# How to add the commits that branch is behind, without losing the commits it is ahead?

Tags: git

I am using Git and created a new branch 'feature' based on a branch called 'development'. As it is now the feature branch is a certain number of commits behind the development branch, as well as a certain number of commits ahead of the development branch.

What is the best way to "import" the commits that the feature branch is behind, into the feature branch? (but without losing the commits that the feature branch is ahead)

P.S. Somewhere in the future I will merge the feature branch into the development branch. I want to already now add the commits that it is behind, as to make this merge go more smoothly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just [rebase](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing) the feature branch with the development branch.

```
git checkout feature_branch
git rebase development
```